# Can I push a commit with "--no-verify" from git gui?

Tags: bash, git

I want to commit some files with a suggestive title, but I can not find a no-verify option.I know that I can do it in bash by simply adding "--no-verify" as a parameter but it would be easier if I can do it directly from gui.